# Pipeline Debug not doing anything

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that I could debug and worked until today - last time when I debugged it and I could see the debug results was this week.
When I click the "Debug" button it stays disabled, as if it would be running, and then it's enabled again, after 2-3 seconds, without any debug occurring.

Only relevant information I found is [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/64), but the solution does not apply to me - I changed the branch to master, the branch that is allowed to publish, I did a successful publish from it, and the debug is still not working:

> I found that error often happens when the publish phase of the Debug fails.
> Try a Publish to see the real error where the Validation fails

Debug Button Disabled after pressing, no output
[image: Debug Button Disabled, no output]

Debug Button Enabled, no output
[image: Debug Button Enabled, no output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LE: I tried to trigger the published pipeline and it failed with the same message, so I guess the link in the original post mentioning Publishing to get the actual error is true, just that in my case I needed to trigger the pipeline as well, not just Publish (publishing did not return an error).

I started to recreate the pipeline from scratch and debug after I was adding each component.
In the end I started to replicate this behaviour when I added the Stored Procedure component in the Foreach.
So I tested the Dataset connectivity for that SP component - I use parameters for its connection data and the test failed - The expression '{item().ClientDbServer}' is not valid: the string character '{' at position '0' is not expected."

So the expression @{items().ClientDBServer} that worked for a parameter in a pipeline does not work in this Stored Procedure. I removed the "{" and "}" and now it debugs.

An error message would have been nice at Debug, but no such thing. Validation passed.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario, inadvertently (or deliberately) creating a self-reference to a pipeline.
For example an error handler that sends an email. The email sending pipeline references the error handler.
This will not throw any sort of validation or debug error. The debug option will not respond.